# Is it intended behavior for a list added to a list to be passed by reference?

Tags: vb.net, list, byref

I noticed something while using a list of lists. It seems that if I have a `List(Of String)` and a `List(Of List(Of String))` that when I add the `List(Of String)` to the `List(Of List(Of String))` that the list of strings gets passed by reference.

For example in the following code:

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

    Dim listRow As New List(Of String)
    Dim listTable As New List(Of List(Of String))

    listRow.Add("Apple")
    listRow.Add("Red")

    listTable.Add(listRow)

    MsgBox(listTable(0)(0))
    MsgBox(listTable(0)(1))

    listRow(0) = "Banana"
    listRow(1) = "Yellow"

    MsgBox(listTable(0)(0))
    MsgBox(listTable(0)(1))

End Sub
```

The first pair of messages will display "Apple" and "Red". Then, after updating listRow, it will display "Banana" and "Yellow". To me this means that the list was added by reference and not by value. I'm looking for confirmation on this, and perhaps a better explanation if there is one?

This is how I've been handling it:

```
Sub AddListItemToMainList(myListRow As List(Of String), myListTable As List(Of List(Of String)))

    Dim newList As New List(Of String)

    newList.Add(myListRow(0))
    newList.Add(myListRow(1))

    myListTable.Add(newList)

End Sub
```

Then just replace `listTable.Add(listRow)` with `AddListItemToMainList(listRow, listTable)`. Obviously my code isn't very dynamic, I'm hardcoding the first and second element, but I'm just testing right now getting the logic and whatnot correct.

If there is a more elegant solution I'm always open to advice.

Comment: `listTable.Add(New List(Of String)(listRow))`

Comment: @Jimi That is for sure a more elegant solution.

Comment: Maybe. It's the same exact thing, though. What's important is that you dereference the original List. Sometimes it's better if it's more *visible*.

Comment: Objects of class type are always passed by reference (even when they're parameters that are identified as `ByVal`; confusingly, this means that the reference is passed by value and thus can't be retargeted in the caller, not that the object itself is passed by value).

Comment: @Craig To be clear, an Object of Class: Type is [this?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=netframework-4.8) And without knowing already, what is the simplest way to find out if an object does or does not belong to that class?

Comment: I mean anything where the type is declared as `Class [x]` (which denotes a "reference type"), as opposed to `Structure [x]` (which denotes a "value type").  (Most of the built-in types aside from `Object` are also value types.  `String` is technically a reference type but it acts like a value type.)

Comment: If you hover over the type in any declaration, the tooltip will include more info on the type.  Possibilities include `Interface` and `Class` which are both reference types, and `Enum` and `Structure` which are both value types.

Comment: @Craig I'm assuming we're both thinking of Visual Studio with the hover effect. When I hover over a String declaration it says `Class System.String`. A List declaration says `Sub List(Of String).New() (+2 Overloads)`. Is it perhaps that if the Type declaration includes `.New()` that it is a reference type?

Comment: No, it's that `List(Of String)` is declared as a `Class`---if I hover over a list declaration, the tooltip is `Class System.Collections.Generic.List(Of T)`.  Most of the things you'll encounter in .NET aside from primitives like `Integer` or `Double` or `Enum`s are reference types.  It's not all that common to work with `Structure` types.

Comment: The reason my tooltip appeared differently is because I was declaring a `List` with the `New` keyword. Without it, I see what you see. I understand the concept of memory allocation. What is messing with my understanding is that setting an array element equal to the element of another array does not behave the same as setting the element of a list equal to the element of another list, though both are Reference Types. I'm looking for the delineation of arrays vs lists on lower level point of view, I guess. If the only factor was reference type vs. value type then the two should act the same, no?

Comment: I find it surprising that array elements would behave differently from list elements when the contained type is a reference type.  I'd expect them both to behave the same way.

Comment: I follow the same line of thought which reiterates my question.